# how to predict the duration until failure?

Tags: classification, cluster-analysis, linear-regression, k-means, prediction

I have a data set of service records of 350 odd entries. in which some details like duration (in months) and "kilometers covered" are there along with the regions info.

All of the records are of one issue of failure of one particular part of a vehicle.

I have to predict how long(month or kilometer ) that part in a new vehicle will last.
PS- I can't share the data.

what do I do?

Comment: please see if this gives you an idea.
https://gist.github.com/shubhranshu90/26889f0a42a26cff6dd842819e1b183f#file-batteryfor-stack-csv

Comment: @rkta please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to set up a regression model where your predictor variables are the region/driver/whatever-the-stuff-maybe and your response is the kilometers covered or duration of time.**

That should get you started in the right direction.

Essentially, you need to pick a regression model that can safely model your data without being influenced by extreme outliers. This will involve some sort of regularization or taking out parts of the data the just seem "odd" (using some sort of statistic)

After your model is set up, then you can just put in new values to predict kilometers covered/duration.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!